# interface for creating objects in c++

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and was trying to practice by writing a student account management software. The class is like the following:

```
class student{
private: 
     string name;
     int student_id;
public:
     void set_value(string in_name, int in_id);
};
```

now I want to create students, WITHOUT using:

```
student student1;
student1.set_value(xx,xx);
```

Instead I was thinking about a way that the user just need to input the name of the student and the object with the same name as the student's name will be created. That way the user need not to know how the dot notation that stuff works. The problem is that I could not create an object by just writing:

```
cout<<"enter the name of the student to create account"<<endl;
string name;
cin>>name;
student name;  //Trying to create an object named with the user input but this statement is invalid
```

So is there any way to work around this? or i am just going in the wrong direction? Maybe I should use something like a linked list, or an array of objects? Or is it a problem of memory allocation?

Comment: Aren't you basically looking for a [constructor](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/constructor_destructor_ordering.html)?

Comment: You should use a constructor.

Comment: Sorry, I might not state my question clearly.I was trying to make unique objects,the name of which is the user input. The user just need to type in the name, and the object with the same name is automatically created.

Comment: And what happens to this object after it's been created?

Comment: @JonathanPotter And I can manipulate on those objects, like setting values, adding more functionality.

Comment: Add I/O methods to your `student` class.  This will allow you to define an instance and input it.

Comment: Objects don't have names in C++ unless you design them like that. If your program creates an instance of a class, it's fundamentally just a chunk of memory that you have a pointer to. You can have a "name" member of the class, and you can use something like a `std::map` to keep track of instances by name, but the instance itself is already unique by virtue of the fact that it's stored at a different location in memory to any other instances of the same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want the *variable name* used in the source code to be determined by the string entered by the user at run-time? But if you don’t know the variable’s name beforehand, when you are writing the program, you can’t refer to it in the program, and thus do anything with it.

It’s like if you had a plan to go to the park next week, walk up to some strangers, and ask their names, and based on their names, come up with specific jokes involving their names. But you want to think of the jokes for those specific people *now*, not next week. How can you even know (right now) what joke to say when you don’t know what their names are?

There are two ways to sort of do what you want.

1) Know every single possible name that could be entered. In your program this would be the equivalent of making

```
student albert;
student annie;
student arthur;
 …

student zach ;
student zoe ;
```

This would be a huge waste of resources, since most of the names will never be entered. In addition, when the program is run the users will be entering strings that have the values of “Bill”, “Sarah”, etc. But there is no intrinsic / automatic connection between the name “Arthur” and the variable `student arthur`. So you would have to set up a big table like

```
   switch (entered_name)
       {
       case “Annie”:
            new_student = annie ; //the already existing object which we created above
       case “Arthur”
            new_student = arthur;
    ….
        }
```

2) Or you could create an array, which is a single named variable containing multiple elements which can be addressed by index (number), not name.

```
student students[1000] ; // students is a fixed-length array that can hold 1000 student objects
```

When the program is run, each successively entered name can then be assigned to the `name` field in the next item in the array, and that object becomes the record for that named student. The program can refer to individual student objects only like `students[45]`. To find the record for Stephen, it will have to manually search through the elements to find the one whose name field is “Stephen”; but there is no variable named `stephen` available to the program, only the array variable `students`.

Clearly option 2 is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The names of things in your program are determined at compile time. You seem to be wanting to make an object name at run time (when the user inputs something). It doesn't work that way. User inputs are data, not variable names.